# One array in multiple array not showing values

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I got this array when I encoded and decoded xml string with json.

```
 [Main] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [ID] => 12345
            [MemberID] => 12345
            [PayerID] => 12345
            [Gross] => 255.35
            [Discount] => .00
            [Net] => 255.35
            [Encounter] => Array (
                [Type] => 1
                [Start] => 08/12/2019 09:58
                [End] => 08/12/2019 10:28
                [StartType] => 1
                [EndType] => 1
                )
            [abcde] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [Type] => Principal
                    [Code] => 1234
                    )
                [1] => Array (
                    [Type] => Secondary
                    [Code] => 1234
                    )
                )
            [Activity] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [ID] => 456789
                    [Type] => 5
                    [Code] => 0095-1234
                    [Quantity] => 2
                    [Net] => 83.00
                    )
                [1] => Array (
                    [ID] => 3432091
                    [Type] => 5
                    [Code] => 0496-56789
                    [Quantity] => 1
                    [Net] => 19.95
                    )
                )
            )


    [1] => Array (
            [ID] => 12345
            [MemberID] => 12345
            [PayerID] => 12345
            [Gross] => 255.35
            [Discount] => .00
            [Net] => 255.35
            [Encounter] => Array (
                [Type] => 1
                [Start] => 08/12/2019 09:58
                [End] => 08/12/2019 10:28
                [StartType] => 1
                [EndType] => 1
                )
            [abcde] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [Type] => Principal
                    [Code] => 1234
                    )
                [1] => Array (
                    [Type] => Secondary
                    [Code] => 1234
                    )
                )
            [Activity] => Array (
                    [ID] => 456789
                    [Type] => 5
                    [Code] => 0095-1234
                    [Quantity] => 2
                    [Net] => 83.00
                [item] => Array (
                    [0] => Array (
                        [Type] => value
                        [Code] => 4576878
                        [Value] => 34456
                        )
                    [1] => Array (
                        [Type] => value
                        [Code] => 4576878
                        [Value] => 34456
                        )
                    [2] => Array (
                        [Type] => value
                        [Code] => 4576878
                        [Value] => 34456
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
```

I have this array. But when I tried to echo values, Activity array in the `$newArr['Main'][1]['Activity'][0]` array is not showing values. When I tried to count the number of activity array, it is showing 6. But there is only one Activity array. I am getting values when I manually call the values with `$newArr['Main'][1]['Activity']['ID']`.

```
$new = simplexml_load_string($real_decoded_xml); 
$con = json_encode($new); 
$newArr = json_decode($con, true); 


      $ClaimArray = $newArr['Main'];
      $main_array_count = sizeof($newArr['Main']);
      for($i=0;$i<$main_array_count;$i++)
      {
        echo $ClaimArray[$i]["ID"].'<br>';
        echo $ClaimArray[$i]["IDPayer"].'<br>';
        echo $ClaimArray[$i]["MemberID"].'<br>';
        echo $ClaimArray[$i]["Gross"].'<br>';
        echo $ClaimArray[$i]["Net"].'<br>';



          $abcdeArray = $ClaimArray[$i]['abcde'];
          $abcdeArray_count = sizeof($abcdeArray);
          for($d=0;$d<$abcdeArray_count;$d++)
          {
             echo $abcdeArray[$d]["Type"].'<br>';
             echo $abcdeArray[$d]["Code"].'<br>';
          }
          $ActivityArray= $ClaimArray[$i]['Activity'];
          $ActivityArray_count = sizeof($ActivityArray);


          for($c=0;$c<$ActivityArray_count;$c++)
          {

                echo $ActivityArray[$c]["ID"].'<br>';
                echo $ActivityArray[$c]["Type"].'<br>';
                echo $ActivityArray[$c]["Code"].'<br>';
                echo $ActivityArray[$c]["Quantity"].'<br>';
                echo $ActivityArray[$c]["Net"].'<br>';

          $itemArray = $ActivityArray[$c]['item'];
          $item_count = sizeof($itemArray);
          for($o=0;$o<$item_count;$o++)
          {
              echo $itemArray[$o]["Type"].'<br>';
                echo $itemArray[$o]["Code"].'<br>';
                echo $itemArray[$o]["Value"].'<br>';

          }

          }



      }
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Because there is no `$newArr['Main'][1]['Activity'][0]`. Use `var_dump($newArr['Main'][1]['Activity'])` to debug the variable further.

Comment: "_it is showing 6_" Because `$newArr['Main'][1]['Activity']` has 6 elements. What data do you expect to show when using `$newArr['Main'][1]['Activity'][0]` (which doesn't exist)?

Comment: `$newArr['Main'][1]['Activity']['item'][0]`. The second row activities wrapped in 'item' key. It has different structure to `['Main'][0]`

Comment: I will be having dynamic activity arrays. How i can show the values?

Comment: "When I tried to count the number of activity array, it is showing 6. But there is only one Activity array" - sizeof() counts elements of array, but not quantity of arrays. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

Comment: It's better to wrap action with arrays, that might not exist, to conditional closures;  _if ( is_array($ActivityArray[$c]['item'])..._

Comment: Count also showing the same 6 only. I am converting dynamic XMLs to array and i want to show the values also. How can i solve this?

Comment: I am still waiting for the solution.